# In Python's multiprocessing module, is it good practice to call a worker pool inside a for loop?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

Is it a good practice to call pool.map inside a for loop to minimize memory usage?

For example, in my code, I'm trying to minimize memory usage by only processing one directory at a time:

PATH = /dir/files

```
def readMedia(fname):
   """ Do CPU-intensive task
   """
   pass

def init(queue):
  readMedia.queue = queue

def main():
  print("Starting the scanner in root " + PATH)

  queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
  pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=32, initializer=init, initargs=[queue])

  for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(PATH):
    full_path_fnames = map(lambda fn: os.path.join(dirpath, fn),
                       filenames)
    pool.map(readMedia, full_path_fnames)

    result = queue.get()
    print(result)
```

The above code, when tested, actually eats up all my memory even when the script is terminated.

Comment: What happens when you set processes=1 or processes=2?  Same behavior?  How many full_path_fnames are you dealing with?  Not sure if os.walk has problems with link cycles.  If you're starting in root it may just be the number of files you're getting with `full_path_fnames=`...  I would find out how many fnames you have and try starting in a directory with just a few files first to see if you can get basic functionality.

Answer (score 3):

There are probably a few issues here. First, you're using too many processes in your pool. Because you're doing a CPU intensive task, you're only going to get diminishing returns if you start more than `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` workers; if you've got 32 workers doing CPU intensive tasks but only 4 CPUs, 28 processes are always going to be sitting around doing no work, but wasting memory.

You're probably still seeing high memory usage after killing the script because one or more of the child processes is still running. Take a look at the process list after you kill the main script and make sure none of the children are left behind.

If you're still seeing memory usage growing too high over time, you could try setting the `maxtasksperchild` keyword argument when you create the pool, which will restart each child process once its run the given number of tasks, releasing any memory that may have leaked.

As for memory usage gains by calling `map` in a for loop, you do get the advantage of not having to store the results of every single call to `readMedia` in one in-memory list, which definitely saves memory if there is a huge list of files being iterated over.

Comment: I have 32 physical cores in this machine (64 virtual cores) so I was actually trying not to use all the resources. After the script is killed, there are no other processes running. Let me try setting maxtasksperchild, thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: Also worth noting: `pool.map` can return the results of each child task directly to the caller (`results = pool.map(...) `) , so you probably don't need to use a queue at all. Depending on what you're doing to aggregate results into that queue, you may see some memory improvements by removing that.